# I am not able use wkhtmltopdf for urls with https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, macos, wkhtmltopdf

I am not able to convert the web pages to pdf using wkhtmltopdf for some websites with https. Here is my console:

```
wkhtmltopdf "https://mywebsite.com" "test.pdf" 
Loading pages (1/5) 
Error: Failed loading page..(sometimes it .....)
```

Why am I getting this error when I can view the page in the browser?

Comment: Just a thought: is your certificate self-signed? What version of wkhtmltopdf did you try?

Comment: wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 No the certificate is not self-signed. I guess thats the problem and have no idea how do solve this with wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: @Nenotlep Do you have any idea how to use wkhtmltopdf for signed certificate. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, no clue really. Maybe try updating to 0.11 or 0.12?

Comment: Currently i am having 0.9.9 version and i am not able to upgrade it to latest version on my mac.